# Angular: Can I use translate with async pipe?

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

What would be the best way to use the translate pipe with the async pipe in an HTML template?

For example, assuming 'foo' and 'bar' had values:

```
{{ 'foo' | translate: '{ bar: (bar$ | async) }' }}
```

appears as empty after compile.

Comment: This should work just fine. Are you saying removing either one of those makes the other one work?

Answer (score 4):

You should **not** add quotes to the `translate` object.

```
<!-- Works! -->
{{ 'foo' | translate: { bar: (bar$ | async) } }}




<!-- Doesn't work -->
{{ 'foo' | translate: '{ bar: (bar$ | async) }' }}

ERROR SyntaxError: Wrong parameter in TranslatePipe. Expected a valid Object, received: { bar: (bar$ | async) } 
at TranslatePipe.push../node_modules/@ngx-translate/core/fesm5/ngx-translate-core.js.TranslatePipe.transform (ngx-translate-core.js:1178)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my case it was caused by a surrounding conditional:

```
<div *ngIf="(obs$|async)">
  {{ 'MSG' | translate:{msg: (obs$|async)} }}
</div>
```

When `obs$` got triggered, the `*ngIf` rendered the inside block. The inside block then subscribed to `obs$` now, but the initial event (that triggered the outside if) is gone now. On the next event, it will render it, however (if it's not empty).

In my case I could easily help myself by using a `BehaviorSubject` for `obs$`, that always starts a new stream with the last seen value. So first, the `*ngIf` gets triggered, the inner block subscribes, then gets triggered immediately with the same value.

You can see it on the simplified example on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-translatepipe, the first block is the non-working code, the second block is how I solved it. However, that trick may not be applicable in all situations.

Answer (score 0):

Put translate pipe after async:
{{ 'foo' | async | translate }}